# Override attribute's methods in scala

Tags: scala, oop, composition, accessor, mutators

In scala it's quite easy to override the default accessors and mutators; this makes me feel much more comfortable with public attributes because it allows me to modify access behavior at a later time without changing my class's signature. Here's how that's done:

```
class Topic {
  var tags = "default"; 
}
```

becomes:

```
class Topic{
  private var _tags = "default"; 
  def tags = {
    _tags
  }
  def tags_ =(s:String){
    _tags = s
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't address a major reason for creating private fields; it doesn't allow for the modification of a component element's behavior. For example, with a Growable, I may want to do something special if I add a new element or clear my list. One way to approach this is to create a class that implements Growable, for example:

```
class Topic {
  private var _tags:Growable[String] = new MyMutableList[String]() 
  def tags = {
    _tags
  }
  def tags_=(Growable[String]){
    _tags = m
  }
}
class MyMutableList[T] extends MutableList[T](){
    override def +=(t:T) {
      println("adding: " + t.toString())
      super.+=(t)
    }
    override def clear() {
      println("clearing")
      super.clear()
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't fix the problem completely because 'tags' can still be set equal to any Growable[String]. This would change the clear() method's behavior to the behavior of whatever type was provided.

Is there anyway to override a method of an attribute in the same way that the attribute's accessor/mutator can be overridden? This doesn't compile, but it expresses what I'm trying to do:

```
class Topic {
  private var _tags:Growable[String] = new MutableList[String](); 
  def tags = {
    _tags
  }
  def tags_=(m:Growable[String]){
    _tags = m
  }
  def tags_.+=(s:String) {
    println("adding: " + t.toString())
    _tags += s
  }
  def tags_.clear(){
    println("clearing")
    _tags.clear()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override the methods of an attribute in a class.

- You could limit the type of your `tags` attribute, to make it
  impossible to set the `tags` attribute to a different
  `Growable[String}`.
- You could also omit the mutator method and add a
  `addTag(tag: String): Unit` and a `cleanTags : Unit` method.

Comment: Two other approaches that come to my mind: 1. You could wrap `m` in the setter (or the getter, as sketched by cscan) and have the wrapping object (delegate) redefine `clear` and `+=`. 2. You could use reflection to override the methods of the `tags`-instance. The latter probably comes closest to what the question is asking. However, considering good design practices, your second point is the way to go.